# Language translation bug in Android application

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, translation

I have a problem with language translation `English -> Spanish` and the other way around.
I have two files in strings resources:

**strings.xml => English**

```xml
<resources>
  <string name="gender_male">Male</string>
  <string name="gender_female">Female</string>
</resources>
```

**strings.xml => Spanish**

```xml
<resources>
  <string name="gender_male">pequeño</string>
  <string name="gender_female">hembra</string>
</resources>
```

For some reason when an application is in RAM memory of a mobile device, but out of focus and I change system language, app chooses previously selected language. It reads wrong recourse file with wrong strings (it reads the previous language). But when I remove the app from RAM memory, select next language in a mobile device, log in again in the app, everything is working fine. It chooses correct resource, with correct strings. Does anyone have some ideas about what is happening?

Comment: Declaring you handle some `configChanges` in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: can you explain me more?  I know where is android manifest.xml, but what to type and where?

Comment: I mean do you have `configChanges="locale"` or such declared for your activity in the manifest file?

Comment: yes, it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle language changing you need to do this via handling the configuration changes.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="locale"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Then in your activity:

```
@Override public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // reapply your strings here
    // invalidating the views should work
    // the line below should force all the views to redraw
    // but you can do a more selective update to improve
    // performance 
    findViewById(android.R.id.content).invalidate()
}
```

In Kotlin:

```
 override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // reapply your strings here
    // invalidating the views should work
    // the line below should force all the views to redraw
    // but you can do a more selective update to improve
    // performance 
    findViewById(android.R.id.content).invalidate()
}
```

Comment: I did this, I added in my activity this code and in my manifest file. But nothing happens, and when I put debug breakpoint at this function onConfigurationChanged , I can't stop here (debug). When is that function is called? Where exactly to put this function in my activity? Also, I need code in Kotlin, not in Java, if you don't know Kotlin never mind, I will translate from Java to Kotlin. Thanks!!!

Comment: if the app is running and you change the locale and return the app to the foreground it should be called. I can show the kotlin version also, it's almost the same.